# Resources loading too slow in my page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a webpage, there's some jQuery on the page that performs the sizing of a div (read more / read less) according to the text placed inside it.

I'm using a custom local font and 90% of the time it works fine, but other times it's over estimating the space needed.

Using the debugger I've found this only happens when the script executes before the page is displaying any of the fonts or icons I'm using (in my resources folder). The Chrome debugger shows that the rendered font is "DejaVu Sans". I'm assuming it's using this count to perform the jQuery after which it replaces the font with my custom font.

I guess this is some kind of loading time problem in terms of the font and as it's inconsistent it's also to do with the cache. But what can I do here? Is there someway to make sure the resources are loaded and available before the dom is ready?

Comment: This comment is more related to how to explain and analyze your problem: the JSP is irrelevant in this case because the issue happens when the JSP is rendered in the client, not while it's being rendered. This makes the issue be in the generated HTML/CSS/JavaScript and on.

Comment: I was just thinking as it's pulling the resources from the server the server and framework might be of some importance in terms of optimisation. I removed to  make it more specific however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a problem of the JQuery running before the font had loaded.
I used the [Web Font Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) custom module (as my font wasn't on google or font squirrel) and callbacks to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

it has been some time since i have done it but you have to optimise it using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
And if you font is available on https://www.google.com/fonts than use that instead

Comment: Would loading a font from outside my web app really be quicker?

Comment: depends on the server. i would suggest using google fonts

Answer (score 1):

`$().ready()` and friends will run as soon as the DOM has been parsed; it won't wait until images and stylesheets and things are loaded.  You might want to check out the JS-native [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event.  From the MDN docs:

> The load event is fired when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading.

So, something like this should work:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM, images, stylesheets etc. all present");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: never fires, I'm guessing the div doesn't fire a load event.

Comment: what `<div>`?  And why are you attaching a listener for `load` on a `<div>` and not on the entire document or window?  If you want to wait until your document loads fonts etc. before counting characters and sizing a div, then wait until the document loads, not the div.

Comment: Oh I see, you mean like using $(window).load(). Practical but I think the performance hit would be a bit too much.